# ASP.NET MVC pass parameters to controller that returns File?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, href, controllers

In a situation when you do not need to pass any parameters below example works fine:

**Controller without parameters:**

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult GetExcelTable()
    {
        XlWorkBook table = new XlWorkBook();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        table.SaveAs(stream);
        return File(stream, MyLib.MIMETypes.GetFileMIMEType(".xlsx"), "Kr-ti-" + Year + "-" + Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ".xlsx");
    }
```

**Client**:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetExcelTable", "Home")">Get excel</a>
```

But what if I want to pass some parameters to the controller and download the file? Is there anyway to simulate the click on `a` tag from jquery and pass the parameters along. I know that you can not get the file with jquery ajax call. 
`Month` and `Year` parameters are on the client side dynamic values that user specifies them in the dropdown list. I have to read this values before the controller is called and pass them to controller.

**Controller with parameters**:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult GetExcelTable(int Month, int Year)
    {
        XlWorkBook table = new XlWorkBook(Month, Year);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        table.SaveAs(stream);
        return File(stream, MyLib.MIMETypes.GetFileMIMEType(".xlsx"), "Kr-ti-" + Year + "-" + Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ".xlsx");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with one of overloads `@Url.Action` that have `routeValues`:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetExcelTable", "Home", new { Month = 9,  Year = 2015})">Get excel</a>
```

If you want to pass them dynamicaly you should use Js, with Jquery it will be:

```
<a id="get-excel">Get excel</a>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $(a#get-excel).click(function(){
                var month = $(select#monthdd).val();
                var year = $(select#yeardd).val();
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("GetExcelTable", "Home")?Month='+ month +'&Year=' + year;
             });
        });
<script/>
```

Comment: Month and year are dynamic values from the dropdown list that user specifies them. I have to get selected values from dropdown list before the Controller is called.